# Set Process Start Sequence with God Gem

Tags: ruby, redis, god, sidekiq

**Is it possible to have God start two processes in sequence?**

I am using Sidekiq which relies on Redis. I would like to start up Redis, then start up Sidekiq, and I have two separate watches set up which work fine independently, however when I run:


`$ god -c "./config.god" -D`



It seems that God tries to launch both simultaneously, resulting in errors from Sidekiq because it can't connect to the Redis server.

My config file for God is below:

```
# config.god
PROJECT_ROOT = ENV['PROJECT_ROOT'] || "/Path/to/app"

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "redis-server"
  w.group = 'conversion-api'
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.start = "/usr/local/Cellar/redis/2.4.16/bin/redis-server"
end

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "sidekiq"
  w.group = 'conversion-api'
  w.interval = 20.seconds
  w.dir = ENV['PROJECT_ROOT'] 
  w.start = "bundle exec sidekiq -v -C #{PROJECT_ROOT}/config.yml -r #{PROJECT_ROOT}/app.rb -c 10"
  w.stop = "bundle exec sidekiqctl stop #{PROJECT_ROOT}/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid 5"
  w.keepalive
  # Don't pass in a pid file location. Let God handle things. Leaving a pid file location in
  # the sidekiq config.yml seems to be harmless though and it lets us force stop sidekiq independently 
  # of God.
  # w.pid_file = File.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid')
  w.log = "./log/god_sidekiq.log"
  w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also, was wondering about controlling startup order. I started looking at the possibility of using the watch transition methods on the sidekiq watch object and checking if the redis process was running: via possibly God.watches["redis"].state == :up and then start sidekiq. Ran out of time and just placed a hack of "sleep 5;" before the sidekiq start and before the redis shutdown.

Comment: Ended up ditching God as it proved to be about as reliable as it's namesake. Switched to Foreman with Upstart.

Comment: I got to spend a little more time on this question. If anybody lands here looking for a solution here is a description on  [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/9evraa).